# How to retrieve stdout / stderr.txt files from Azure Batch compute nodes using python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-batch

The .NET documentation for Batch includes a method for retrieving files off a node in the pool: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.computenode.getnodefile?view=azure-dotnet) The corresponding classes in the [python SDK](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.batch.html) don't have any methods. What is the best way of returning the stderr.txt file for a task when it fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do that by using the python `batch_client`, I found a implementation here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/doc/batch.rst

```
# Download task output
with open('task_output.txt', 'w') as file_output:
        output = batch_client.file.get_from_task(
                'python_test_job',
                'python_task_1',
                'stdout.txt'
        )
        for data in output:
                file_output.write(data)
```

Comment: The git link is not working. Can you post your complete implementation